# Ubuntu 12.10 desktop Turns Black When booting

Tags: 12.10

I have Hp laptop with windows 8.Now i install ubuntu 12.10 in a different drive.fist time it opens.But next time when booting in ubuntu it turns black and not responding.In my laptop ubuntu 12.04 lts goes smooth,but 12.10 not.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot and the screen turns black, have you tried turning up the brightness using the f2 and f3 keys? I have the same problem when booting my Pavilion m6. Once you adjust the brightness you should be able to log in normally. There is probably a way to adjust the default brightness but I'm not sure how. Anyone else?